Distribute messages to multiple recipients with Sieve (prevent double-mailing)
Maybe an easy question for some of you but I'm struggling to realize some Email distribution using Sieve and a catchall-address.
What I want is the following:

All Emails to shop-XXX@example.org shall be redirected to mailbox1@example.org, where XXX can be any (Email compliant) string.
All Emails to alias47@example.org shall be redirected to mailbox2@example.org
All Emails that are not redirected by a previous rule go into the default catchall mailbox.

The scripts, I tried so far, work fine in most cases. However, if an Email is sent, e.g., to shop-XXX@example.org and alias47@example.org at the same time, the distribution does not work correctly anymore. Here is what I tried:
if address :localpart :matches ["To", "Cc"] "shop-*" {
  redirect "mailbox1@example.org";
} elsif address :localpart :is ["To", "Cc"] "alias47" {
  redirect "mailbox2@example.org";
} else {
  keep;
}

The problem is that if an Email is sent To: alias47@example.org and Cc: shop-XXX@example.org, then the Email ends up twice with mailbox1@example.org.
If I change the script to
if address :localpart :matches ["To", "Cc"] "shop-*" {
  redirect "mailbox1@example.org";
}
if address :localpart :is ["To", "Cc"] "alias47" {
  redirect "mailbox2@example.org";
}
keep;

and the Email is sent To: alias47@example.org and Cc: shop-XXX@example.org, then the Email ends up twice with mailbox1@example.org, twice with mailbox2@example.org and also twice with the default catchall mailbox.
From a logical point of view, I fully understand why the Emails are distributed that way. Now, the questions is, is there a way to distribute the Email in the way I want to have them or can this only be achieved with separate mailboxes? Is it possible to introduce variables to check if the same Email has been sent to a certain mail address before?
Thanks for your thoughts.

Catch all redirection based on To,CC headers is flawed by  design. Which MTA/SMTP server do you use (or can use)?

@AnFionet.eu, thanks for your reply. I'm using uberspace.de as webhosting service, so did not set up the SMTP server myself. I understand they are using Dovecot and Postfix when it comes to Emails.
